# IE9 "select element by click" inside an HTML explorer bar

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Is it possible to expand the "select element by click" functionality (part of the F12 developer tools) on HTML explorer bars in IE9 (currently working for me on normal IE windows/tabs but not on HTML explorer bars)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no. You could try debugging your bar's HTML in a normal page.

Comment: Debugging the bar's HTML in a normal page might be problematic when (like in my case) the bar's code interacts with the normal page (the communication is established by a BHO and another COM object instantiated by a javascript code in the bar's domain). Thus the bar's DOM is always built by this interaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more debugging info than you're getting from the F12 Developer Tools in IE, you might try the Firebug Lite JS bookmarklet ([find it here](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)). I find it invaluable for solving problems with dynamic pages, because the F12 tools don't show any updates to the HTML after the initial page load.